# n-EMOSFET circuit analysis

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

[image]

This circuit is n-EMOSFET circuit, V<sub>TH</sub>=3V, K=1mA/V<sup>2</sup>, find V<sub>GS</sub>, I<sub>D</sub> and V<sub>D</sub>.

V<sub>o</sub> = 15-3300I<sub>D</sub>

I<sub>D</sub> = (15 -V<sub>o</sub>)/3300

V<sub>D</sub> = 3300I<sub>D</sub>

Since I<sub>G</sub>=0, V<sub>GS</sub>=V<sub>DS</sub>=V<sub>o</sub>

I<sub>D</sub> = (15 -V<sub>o</sub>)/3300 = 1mA/V<sup>2</sup> (V<sub>GS</sub>- V<sub>TH</sub>)/2

I<sub>D</sub> = (15 -V<sub>o</sub>)/3300 = 1mA/V<sup>2</sup> (V<sub>o</sub>- V<sub>TH</sub>)/2

From this equation, I got V<sub>o</sub> , then I can find V<sub>GS</sub>, V<sub>D</sub> and I<sub>D</sub>.

Please correct me whether I got it right?

Comment: Vgs is the simple voltage-divider formed by R1 and R2 and has no relation to Vds.

Comment: 15 -  Rd x Id - Vgs = 0 , is that right ?

Comment: No. 15 - Rd x Id - V**d**s = 0.

Answer (score 1):

For this circuit the Source terminal is connected directly to ground. And the Gate is connected the voltage divider output. Therefore
$$
 Vgs = V_{DD}*\frac{R2}{R1+R2} = 15V\frac{18k\Omega}{47k\Omega+18k\Omega} = 4.153V   
$$

Drain current is equal to:

$$
I_D = K(V_{GS} - V_{TH})^2 = 1mA/V^2 *(4.153V - 3V)^2 = 1.329mA 
$$

Additional form KVL we have:

$$V-{DD} = I_D*R_D+V_{DS}$$

$$V_{DS} = V_{DD}-I_D*R_D = 15V - 1.329mA*3.3k\Omega = 10.6V $$

Now we need to check if MOSFET is in saturatuion \$V_{DS} >(V_{GS} - V_{TH})\$

In our case **10.6V > 1.153V** this means our assumption about MOSFET active region (saturation) is true.